# Headless Magento 2: Need custom URL instead of domain/products/:SKU

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite, headless

Fairly new to to magento. I am going for a headless approach, where I have created product listing pages with URLs as:

> www.domain.com/products/:productSKU

I want to change this to something like:

> www.domain.com/products/product-name

**I have created a mapping of sorts in form of a dictionary/JSON/Text file, with productSKU as key and product-name as value.**

Is there a way to do this? I read a little about NGNIX rewrites, but not sure if that'll work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the urls 
In magento 2 please go to 
admin >> Marketing >> SEO & Search >> url rewrites 
click on Add url rewrites
select category and in target path add your sku path which is coming right now and in request path add the url you want adn then save.
run below commands
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean